# How to pick up files from a unix directory and transfer them to aure Blob storage or S3 bucket using Java

Tags: java, file, unix, sftp

I have a unix directory from where i have to pick up specific files and then i have to drop them to a s3 bucket either or into a azure blob storage. I have written the code for the same

```
public class JSchExampleSSHConnection {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String host="my.host.com";
    String user="iamUser";
    String password="iampass";
    String watchFolder ="//usd/sync$/TestRepo/TestFiles/"; // folder from where i want to pull the files & this this path exactly the same of the unix directory 
    String filemask = "*.csv";
    JSch jsch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;
    Channel channel = null;
    Integer port = 22;
    
    try{
        
         session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);

         session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
         session.setPassword(password);

         session.connect();

         channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
         channel.connect(); //connected here 
         ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp)channel;

         // Go through watch folder looking for files.
         File[] files = findFile(watchFolder, filemask);
         for(File file : files) {
             // Upload file. // i can call a function from here which can push the files into s3/blob storage 
             System.out.print(file);           
         }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static File[] findFile(String dirName, final String mask) {
    File dir = new File(dirName);
    return dir.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        public boolean accept(File dir, String filename)
            { return filename.endsWith(mask); }
    } );
   
}
}
```

But the problem with my code is that it is not returning me the files. Can anyone help me where i am doing wrong here .

Answer (score 0):

```
String filemask = "*.csv";
...
public boolean accept(File dir, String filename)
    { return filename.endsWith(mask); }
}
```

I guess you're trying to find filenames ending in ".csv"? Your `filemask` looks like it's supposed to be a [wildcard expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_character), due to the fact it begins with an asterisk.

However, you're passing `filemask` to `[String.endsWith()][2]`. This method doesn't do wildcard matching. It's going to check for a filename ending with a literal "*.csv" including the asterisk. That would only match a filename containing a literal asterisk.

If you want to look for filenames ending with ".csv", make your filemask ".csv".